# Destroy embedded documents based on a field set by attar_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

Following classes are defined in my rails application:

```
class Letter
    embeds_many :dispatches

    def evaluate
        self.dispatches.destroy_all(marked: true)
    end
end

class Dispatch
    embedded_in :letter

    attr_accessor :marked
end
```

During my program execution some dispatches will be marked, i.e. I will set "marked" attribute to true.

When I call the evaluate method on a Letter instance, I expect the marked dispatches embedded in this letter to be destroyed. But nothing happen...

Is it possible to pass attributes created by attar_accessor to destroy_all method?

Comment: Why are you using `attr_accessor :marked` rather than `field :marked`? `attr_accessor` won't give you persistent values.

Comment: Mainly because I do not require the value to be persisted to database. Some of these items will be marked and immediately after destroyed from database so I believe it is not necessary to store this field in database. In the end I might have no other option to do so but I'm really interested to know if it is possible to do it in this manner and whether it is a good practice or not. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough. Could you keep a list of `id`s somewhere instead of marking them? Or go through the list manually to find the marked dispatches and get them that way?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have to agree that both options are feasible and can be implemented without substantial difficulties. I guess there is no going around it.